# Images not displayed in collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a collection view cell and inside there's an imageView. On it I display array of images using `sd_setImage` once loaded from firestore. In console I see all images which my app downloaded.

I use this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "newDetailCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! NewDetailCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[indexPath.item]))

    return cell
}
```

[image]

When I use this code I can't see my images. But if I use the code below everything works fine.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "newDetailCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! NewDetailCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[indexPath.item]))

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you just set break point at numberOfItemsInSection and print "images.count"?

Comment: Please add whole code.

Comment: @VDPurohit if i print `images.count` i see 1 item. But i still have tableView and tableView showed me images.count = 10

Comment: @KeyurHirani i added code, i think more code does not need to solve the problem

Comment: i see all images in console, but why my images doesn't want to appear? delegate and datasource I did in mainstoryboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should be calling `collectionView.reloadData()` instead of `tableView.reloadData()` in your `Dispatch.main.async {}` Because in this situation the `collectionView` needs to update the dataSource. I Hope this helps.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I figured out the problem. What you said didn't help, but it helped me to understand what I have a problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Dima do you mind sharing what was your problem? I'm having a similar issue